# SCO binaries on linux

Tags: linux, kernel, sco

I have a situation where we are moving our sco based server to linux but need 3 sco programs to run. I know there is a kernel patch that should allow me to do that but that is where I am stuck.

Comment: The situation does not look promising AFAIK http://ibcs64.sourceforge.net

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/linux-abi/discussion/41354/thread/9159eace/

Answer (score 1):

Seems Russell Stuart forked ibcs-us in 2019. https://ibcs-us.sourceforge.io/. It's a user space implementation that might do the thing. Of course, it might not help for the original problem, but ibcs still lives.

Comment: Looks like it [runs on Debian Bullseye](https://ibcs-us.sourceforge.io/ChangeLog.txt), so that is quite promising

Answer (score 0):

It's called ibcs2 but it has not been maintained since about 2011, and probably will not work with a current Linux kernel. Though there is a fork of linux-abi called [ibcs64](https://ibcs64.sourceforge.net/), which again got forked into [ibcs-us](https://ibcs-us.sourceforge.io/), which is a userspace based implementation. The latter is still maintained.